# How to build npm package from source

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm new to npm/node and I'm trying to build this repository:
https://github.com/react-component/slider

After clone and run `npm install`, I get this error:

```
/Users/rodrigora/Projects/slider/node_modules/rc-server/lib/index.js:39
  app.get('/tests/runner.html', function* () {
                                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rodrigora/Projects/slider/node_modules/rc-server/bin/start.js:3:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

I've reinstalled node/npm, deleted `node_modules` folder but nothing worked.

```
$ node -v
v0.12.0
$ npm -v
3.5.2
```

I don't have a clue how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: Update to a stable/LTS version of node; version 4 or 5. Otherwise run `node` with `--harmony-generators`

Comment: lol @ExplosionPills. Thanks!!

Comment: Don't know if this is still relevant but I've seen `npm_config_build_from_source=true` mentioned a few places. Could be worth trying (though I can't find docs on it).